# save mails from webmail locally (no IMAP or POP access)

Tags: email, domain, webmail, roundcube

This is a quite general question, but I have no more ideas. I have a domain with an email-address accessible via webmail. This package does not allow me to receive mails via IMAP or POP. I now need to move the domain to another provider where I already have a hosting package (I do this for a friend and he already paid for this hosting package at the other provider, so there is no other option).

Long story short: I need to move/copy the mails from the old provider to the new provider. However, I only have access to the mails from the old provider via webmail. Is there some way to easily save/backup the mails from the webmail?

I know, the question is general, but I have no single idea on how to do this.

EDIT: 
the webmail is roundcube, but it seems it is a highly customized version.

Comment: I downvoted this question because, in the absense of advise as to what webmail program is being used, no one can help you any more then saying write a script to scrape and parse the emails.  Even then, your best bet may be to get in touch with your mail provider and ask them for alternative access or a copy of the underlying spool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is try to contact the provider, and see if they can help export it, if not give you the `POP3` or `IMAP` settings. In some countries offering this service may even be required by law.

If that yields no results, I have a few options in my RoundCube webmail, which I hope you have too.

One is to highlight an individual mail, click the `More` button and Select **Download (.eml)**. Unfortunately that only appears to work on individual e-mails.

Another is simply to forward each e-mail individually to your new account or some temporary address/webserver.

But actually it seems there's a *better* way:
If you highlight multiple files and select **Forward** (or click the arrow and select **Forward as attachment**) it appears as if what you're sending is an e-mail with all the e-mails selected attached as `.eml` files. Maybe you can try that selecting all of them, and see if you can import them successfully afterwards? How that works if the e-mails themselves have attachments I'm not so sure about, but at least this could mass export all the ones without attachment if not all of them in general.

These `.eml` files can probably be imported into your new host, or at least imported to a mail program, that can then in turn move it to the new host if you have `IMAP` access to that.

Some information on importing `.eml` files into the mail client `Thunderbird`, as an example:
http://www.emailadept.com/import-emails-to-thunderbird.htm

Comment: wow thanks. I was aware of downloading invidivdual mails as .eml, but I did not know about highlighting multiple files + forward as attachment! I just tried this with an email which has an attachement: The resulting .eml-file then also has the attachment, so that looks promising. will report back later.